# Validar valores

Tags: r

Parto de un df y quiero ver si los datos que contiene son correctos.

```
   df <- read.table(text = '
         id     col2  col3     col4
         1       N      H        A
         2       N     H        B
         3       S      M        C
         4       S      M        C
         5       S      M        D
         6       N      M        E
         7       S     M        B', header = TRUE)
```

La función (mal) para validar sería algo parecido a esto:

```
validar_campos <- function (columna, valores_permitidos){
  
  columna <- deparse(substitute(columna))
  names(table(df[,columna])) -> tabla
  contador <- 0
  
  for(i in tabla){
    if ( !i %in% valores_permitidos)
    {
    contador = contador+1 
    incorrectos <- c(i)}
  }
  
  if (contador == 0) {
    x <- print ("Todos los valores son correctos")
  }
  
  else { 
    x <- cat(paste("Hay valores incorrectos:",incorrectos))
  }
  return(x)
}

validar_campos( col4, c("A","B"))
```

Me tendría que salir que la columna 4 tiene valores no permitidos (c d, e)

El siguiente paso sería que también dijera en que ID está el error (3,4,5,6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay algunos problemas:

Primero, hay que incluir el df en la función.

Segundo, hay que poner los valores en una lista - con la función como lo tiene, `incorrectos` cambia con cada iteración al ultimo valor.

Tercero, se usa `cat`, `print`, y `paste`.

Esas funciones son levemente distintas. `paste` reenvía un vector de caracteres concatenados. `print` se usa para mostrar una frase. `cat` se usa para combinar frases y mostrarlas.

Es difícil capturar las salidas de `cat` y `print`. Para capturar `cat`:

```
# Este no funciona
x <- cat("frase")
#> frase
x
#> NULL

# Este funciona
x <- capture.output(cat("frase"))
x
#> [1] "frase"
```

Es aún más difícil capturar `print`. No es posible capturar `print` bien sin mostrar la frase en la consola a la misma vez.

```
# Este no funciona
x <- print("frase")
#> [1] "frase"
x
#> [1] "frase"

# Este no funciona
x <- capture.output(print("frase"))
x
#> "[1] \"frase\""
```

La opción mejor para combinar frases y salvarlas en un objeto es `paste` o `paste0`.

La funciona debe funcionar así:

```
validar_campos <- function(df,
                           columna,
                           valores_permitidos) {
  
  columna <- deparse(substitute(columna))
  names(table(df[,columna])) -> tabla
  contador <- 0
  incorrectos <- list()

  for(i in tabla) {
    if (!i %in% valores_permitidos) {
      contador = contador+1 
      incorrectos <- append(incorrectos, i)
    }
  }
  
  if (contador == 0) {
    x <- paste0("Todos los valores son correctos")
  } else { 
    x <- paste0(
           "Hay valores incorrectos: ", 
           paste0(incorrectos, collapse = ",")
         )
  }

  return(x)
}

validar_campos(df,  col4, c("A","B"))
```

Me gusta usar `paste0` en lugar de `paste` porque `paste` automáticamente incluye espacios entre las frases. Con `paste0`, solo incluye los caracteres exactos que tu incluyes.

Por ejemplo:

```
x <- paste("frase", "frase2")
x
#> [1] "frase frase2"

y <- paste0("frase", "frase2")
y
#> "frasefrase2"
```